# google map shows only one forth part at left

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Hey i m working on google MAP ..I have implemented google map by using Google Maps ices, But when the page refresh map displaying only in the left top corner of div container, i.e displaying only the one forth portion of div container, and the other part is blank. but when i press F12 for inspecting the code (Firebug), it will display completely. i Can not understand what's going on...

```
  <div id="dvMap" >
      </div> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api /js?sensor=false">

 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;  
var markers = [
       <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server" >
       <ItemTemplate>
                {
                       // "title":  '<%#Regex.Replace(Eval("HotelNamelabel").ToString(),"/\\W\\d\\S\\[\\w'-]/",string.Empty) %>',
                        "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                        "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                       // "description": '<%#Regex.Replace(String.Format("{0} , {1} , {2}",Eval("HotelNamelabel"),Eval("HotelLocation"),Eval("HotelCity")),"/\\W\\d\\S\\[\\w'-]/",string.Empty) %>'

                    }

        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
            ,
            </SeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
    ];


    window.onload = function () {
       var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"),  mapOptions);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'resize', function(){
                alert('div resize');
                google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
            });

          for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var data = markers[i]
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title
                });
                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
            }


    }
```

Comment: The symptom you describe typically occurs when a Google map is initialized on a hidden canvas. So ensure the canvas is fully rendered and visible when `var map = new google.maps.Map(...)` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Beetroot said in his comment, you can overcome the issue by using the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#yourMapContainer').on('shown', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
});
```

If indeed the map is in a hidden element such as a modal window, place this call in separate JS file i.e. your main site JS file.

Comment: It should work. I had the exact same problem. Can you update your Q with some more info - is the map being rendered in a hidden canvas i.e. modal window? Are you sure the changes you've made to your JS file are being recognised i.e. old version of file not being cached in browser?

Comment: can i know that how can i access map in saperate js file as google.map.event.trigger()  in  which how can i access map

Comment: You'll access the map using a jQuery selector `$('#myMapCanvas')` but obviously you will need to select **your** map so you'd go something like `$('#dvMap')`