# Gmaps not working properly on js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap

I've a gmap loading problem with Google JavaScript API and it does not load completely when initialized the project. I tried all of available solutions but it did not work. In addition, if reloaded or resized the page, it works.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDWTQpi0GTmb6hoIjbBlcGYfZLAkaDmqLI"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gmaps")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var map = new GMaps({
                div: '#gmap_basic',
                lat: 25.261502,
                lng: 55.29155,
                zoom: 15,
                width: '100%',
                height: '300px',

            });
            map.addMarker({
                lat: 25.261502,
                lng: 55.29155,
            });
        })
    </script>
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div id="gmap_basic" class="gmaps"></div>
</div>
```

Just seems top left of the page! how can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle sample? Thanks.

Comment: i tried it, but not worked.

Comment: This is due to improper assignment of dimensions(width and height).  Try adding fixed dimensions or do a [map refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23983187/1671639)

Comment: Can you give a sample for correct dimensions? Because I try every type of dimensions, but I don't get positive results. Also, I tried to refresh the map,but still it is not working,

Comment: for example as   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

Comment: This stackoverflow post maybe can help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276035/google-map-shows-only-one-forth-part-at-left
or this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689656/google-maps-window-only-showing-part-of-the-map
or this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982996/google-map-only-loads-half-of-its-portion-i-have-used-some-extra-javascript-for?lq=1

Comment: Thanks bro! I implemented them earlier, but not be changing anything.

Comment: I'm sure. There is a very simple solution but it will take for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using "bootstrap" my project. So, bootstrap provides a method to do this with the [shown.bs.'your element tag'](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) event. And I solved the problem. I hope that it will be useful to everbody.

**Html**

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div id="gmap_basic" class="gmaps"></div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabGmap').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                var Lat = 'your map lat';
                var Lon = 'your map lon';
                var map = new GMaps({
                    div: '#gmap_basic',
                    lat: Lat,
                    lng: Lon,
                    zoom: 14,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '300px',
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lon)

                });
                map.addMarker({
                    title: 'Map title',
                    lat: Lat,
                    lng: Lon
                });
            });
        })

    </script>
```

**Output**
[image]